# how to implement tree topology using c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a root node and some child nodes for that root node.I want the structure to be aligned as the below example.Can any one tell me how to approach for doing this.

[image]

on click of any node i need  to get the details of that node.I am thinking that it is complicated.

Comment: Is your question about how to implement a tree datastructure from scratch or how to visualize that in a GUI application? If the later, are you using WPF, WinForms or some other toolkit?

Comment: You are looking for a custom user control. Did you search for any already-made controls for this purpose? Check codeproject.com or other similar websites.

Comment: Is it fixed to 4 levels? Or is your tree varying?  Can you use HTML5?

Comment: It's probably possible in HTML5 but I'm sure about Silverlight. But it's going to be a substantial project. You can maybe get some starters here, but you're sill very short on details.

Comment: Ok let me tell u my requirement.I am having the data of tree root node and and it's child nodes.I want to display that in GUI in a tree structure.i want the code only to display that.As of now i am displaying it in treeview.I want to design the gui.This is the requirement.Admin can add or remove nodes and on clicking on any of the node i should get the details of that particular node like its parent node is x and child node is y or so.

Comment: Can you tell us [what you have already tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - this is a substantial problem that can be solved in a number of different ways (HTML 5 canvas, image maps, Flash, Silverlight, lots of CSS etc...) - each has their own advantages and disadvantages and all of them are far from simple.  You should also take a look through some of the questions listed here: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+tree+graph+ASP.Net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I tried creating buttons and assigning the node values to the buttons.But i am not able to do that as i am not getting it in a tree structure.I am checking whether a root node is there ,if there i am creating a button.If child nodes are there i am creating buttons under that root button.This is the way i am doing.I need any of t he way which is the best to do this

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are trying to implement a binary tree.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/implementing-a-generic-binary-tree-in-c/) to solve your problem.

Comment: I need the GUI sir,not the tree view.I got it in tree view.but i want the GUI to be as i posted the image